# How to graphically compare predicted and actual values from multivariate regression in R?

Tags: r, regression, multivariate-analysis, multiple-regression

I'm trying to write a function to graphically display predicted vs. actual relationships in a linear regression.  What I have so far works well for linear models, but I'd like to extend it in a few ways.

1. Handle glm models
2. Deal with NAs in the predicted values

Does what I have so far seem like a good solution, or is there an existing package somewhere that's already implemented this?

```
DF <- as.data.frame(na.exclude(airquality))
DF$Month <- as.factor(DF$Month)
DF$Day <- as.factor(DF$Day)

my_model <- lm(Ozone~Solar.R+Wind+Temp+Month+Day,DF)

PvA<- function(model,varlist=NULL,smooth=.5) { #Plot predicted vs actual for a model

    indvars <- attr(terms(model),"term.labels")

    if (is.null(varlist)) {
        varlist <- indvars
    }

    Y <- as.character(as.list(attr(terms(model),"variables"))[2])
    P.Y <- paste('P',Y,sep='.')

    DF <- as.data.frame(get(as.character(model$call$data)))
    DF[,P.Y] <- predict.lm(model)

    par(ask=TRUE)
    for (X in varlist) {
        print(X)
        A <- na.omit(DF[,c(X,Y)])
        P <- na.omit(DF[,c(X,P.Y)])
        plot(A)
        points(P,col=2)
        lines(lowess(A,f=smooth),col=1)
        lines(lowess(P,f=smooth),col=2)
    }

}
PvA(my_model)
```

Comment: have you tried plot on the `lm` or `glm` object? How what you are trying to achieve is different from what `plot.lm` does?

Comment: @mpiktas I'm looking for something to supplement plot.lm or plot.glm.  Plot.lm shows residuals vs Fitted, Scale-Location, Normal Q-Q and Residuals vs. leverage plots.  What I'm looking for is plots of the actual relationship between Solar.R and and Ozone, and the predicted relationship from my model.  Run my example code, and you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to @mpiktas's comment, you can also have a look at the [rms](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rms/index.html) package from Frank Harrell. The advantage is that it handles both LM and GLM for model fitting and prediction; see for example the `plot.Predict()` function. If you're planning to do serious job in regression modeling, this package and its companion [Hmisc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html) are really good.

Comment: I'd also recommend the car package (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/car/index.html)